# Receiving every multicast packet twice Onload?

Tags: c, linux, udp, multicast, openonload

I am listening to multicast data from an external source.

When my application runs **without** `Onload`, everything is fine. However, when I run under `Onload` I receive every packet twice.

This is how I join the multicast group:

```c
struct ip_mreq mreq;
bzero(&mreq,sizeof(mreq));
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("233.1.2.3");
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.1.2.3");

if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
    ...
```

How can I run under `Onload` without receiving every packet twice?

Comment: What is `Onload`? I don't think it is the JavaScript `Onload` the question is tagged with.

Comment: @jww Solarflare Onload

Comment: Did you find a solution? Because I have the same problem

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi It was a while ago now but I think it was to do with Linux routing tables.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for a packet being seen twice in the application is that it is arriving twice to the host, either twice on the same interface or on different interfaces. Try running a packet capture (`tcpdump` or `onload_tcpdump`) to confirm if this is the case.

This behaviour is different from the kernel where packets arriving on the "wrong" interface are dropped. Onload will typically install a filter on all accelerated interfaces to capture traffic and not just the one specified by the application.